# How to run a batch file using powershell DSC?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, automation, dsc

I need to run a file.bat using DSC resources. The only way I was able to successfully execute the file.bat was by using the `Package` resource. However I receive the following error:

> PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_PackageResource  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: Package 
>   from Directory\To\MyFile\file.bat was installed, but the specified ProductId and/or 
>   Name does not match package details

I know the meaning of the error, and I have previously resolved it. However, there is no productId nor a Name for a batch file.

How else can I run a batch file using DSC?

Comment: Embed batch file into a script resource?

Comment: It doesn't work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Nope, but I can't see why it shouldn't. If this batch file doesn't exist on a target machine, store it in the variable using here-string (`$batch = @' ..code.. '@`), then dump it to the file (`$batch | Out-File -Encoding ascii -Force -FilePath 'X:\path\to\mybatch.cmd'`) and run using `& .\mybatch.cmd`. If this this doesn't work for you, then post more details about what's going wrong.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!!! I was using `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {C:\choco\lib\elasticsearch\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin\service.bat install}` and `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {start C:\choco\lib\elasticsearch\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin\service.bat install}`. However, `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& C:\choco\lib\elasticsearch\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin\service.bat install}` worked. I assume `& C:\choco\lib\elasticsearch\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin\service.bat install` would work, but I don't care. Thank you a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to count the question as answered. Thank you @beatcracker for providing the answer.

Use the `Script resource` and in the `SetScript` script block use

`& your\batch\file\directory.yourBatchFile.bat optionalArguments`

If that doesn't work, try

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& your\batch\file\directory.yourBatchFile.bat optionalArguments}`

:D

Comment: Thanks this helped me to make a Script to install VSTS Agent on a server. You can also access variables in the SetScript via $using  e.g.         `SetScript =  { & $using:VstsAgentUnzippedPath\config.cmd --unattended --auth PAT --token $using:PatToken --agent $using:AgentName --pool $using:PoolName --runAsService --url $using:TfsUrl --windowsLogonAccount 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' }`